# Why doesn't jQuery 1.3.3. live() support all events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've just been pondering the jQuery `live()` event binder, which seems like a really useful function.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

One thing I note is that it doesn't support all events:

> "**Currently not supported**: blur, focus,
>   mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit"

My (very simple) mind reasons that surely if it were implemented for one event, it would be easy to do it for all others?

Clearly its wasn't that simple, so I wondered if anyone knows why it was so difficult to do it for all others?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because it uses event delegation. The problem is that event delegation based on event bubbling. And events are bubbling not for all events.
you can read more here: [JavaScript Event Delegation is Easier than You Think](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it:

When you use `live()` an event handler is attached to the `document`.

**Why?**

Given this snippet:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">my link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you click or move the mouse on the `<a>` tag, you have to remember that your `<a>` is sitting inside an `<li>` which is inside a `<ul>` in a `<body>` in `<html>` which is inside the `document`. No matter what HTML structure you have, every element exists within the `document`.

So, when you click the link, you're actually also clicking all those other elements too, it's just that the link is sitting on top`*` of that stack. This is called *bubbling* - the click event starts on the link and bubbles up through each of its parents finally reaching the `document`. Any time you click *any* element you're also clicking the `document`.

Therefore, if you place an event listener on the `document` to handle clicks, it can check where *else* was clicked in that same event before it bubbled to the `document`. The `live()` function simply stores the query string you provided and compares that against all clicked (or `mousemove`d, etc) elements and fires your function if it gets a hit.

The others: `blur`, `focus`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `change`, `submit` are all events which don't bubble, therefore they can't be used with `live()`.

**Why don't they bubble?**

Because if you think about it, it doesn't make sense. If you focus an element, you are only focusing *one* element, not its parents and ancestors. Similarly with the others - the events never reach the document so you can't use this technique.

> `*`: as with many "tree" metaphors in computing, terms like "up" and "top" can be a bit confusing. Though your link is visually rendered at the top, it's probably more helpful to think of it as at the bottom. The events bubble upwards through parents and reach the top level element which is the "root". `:-/`