# jQuery select "change" event not fired

Tags: jquery, events, select

I have three depending selects.
First one, have some values.

```
<select id="first">
<option value="1">v1</option>
<option value="2">v2</option>
</select>
```

Second and third are blank:

```
<select id="second"></select>
<select id="third"></select>
```

I want to populate blank selects via ajax requests.
So I do:

```
jQuery('body').delegate('#first','change',function(){
jQuery.ajax(
{
'type':'GET',
'data':{'changed':$('#first').val()},
'url':'myURL1',
'cache':false,
'success':function(html){jQuery("#second").html(html)}});
return false;
});
```

So it works fine. The second select is populated, but... no 'change' event is fired for select 'second'.
To get this event, I have wrote:

```
   $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#second').live("change", function()
        {
            alert('test');
        });
    });
```

But no alert 'test' is visible. How to catch this 'change' event for dynamically loaded content for second select?

Comment: Have you tried adding the assignment of the change event inside of the success callback of the AJAX?

Comment: Do you want to rise the change event of #second right after loading the data? If you manually change the second select, then the alert box should be shown with your actual code.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: By the way: I would acoid mixing jQuery() and $()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the #second element just exists don't have to use the delegate and live functions

```
$('#first').change(function(){ 
  $.ajax( 
  { 
    'type':'GET', 
    'data':{'changed':$('#first').val()}, 
    'url':'myURL1', 
    'cache':false, 
    'success':function(html){
      $("#second").html(html);
     }
   }); 
   return false; 
});

$('#second').live("change", function()   
{   
  alert('test');   
});
```

if you want to do the alert right after populating the second select, then include it in your callback function of the $.ajax()

```
$('#first').change(function(){ 
  $.ajax( 
  { 
    'type':'GET', 
    'data':{'changed':$('#first').val()}, 
    'url':'myURL1', 
    'cache':false, 
    'success':function(html){
      $("#second").html(html);
      $("#second").change();
     }
   }); 
   return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$('#second').change(function(){
    alert('Test')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of jQuery are you using? Anything prior to 1.4.x didn't support `live` events for `change`.

(see [Why doesn't jQuery 1.3.3. live() support all events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267072/why-doesnt-jquery-1-3-3-live-support-all-events))

Here is the API for it http://api.jquery.com/live/

You can see in the caveats:

> In jQuery 1.3.x only the following
>   JavaScript events (in addition to
>   custom events) could be bound with
>   .live(): click, dblclick, keydown,
>   keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove,
>   mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup.

Comment: Changed to .change(function() { }) with no result

Answer (score 0):

as far jquery update its version from jQuery 1.7 its introduce "on" see here http://api.jquery.com/on/ . So if you use following way definately it will call "Change" event.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#second').on("change", function()
    {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```